# HOWTO: post messages between threads with Boost::asio?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

Sorry for my english

I've searched around, but did not get an answer to this question: 
I have a windows application project, using boost thread libraries. I want to post messages(or, invoke callbacks) from a worker's thread to the main UI thread. I studied the samples in boost::asio, all of them used in a blocked main thread, but my UI thread is working asynchronous.

Would you please help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the UI thread has its own message loop, you can't call in its context the blocking `io_service::run()` function. What you can do is to interleave a polling UI-related method with `io_service::poll_one()`:

```
  // WARINING: untested code
  MSG msg;
  while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    if (io_service_.stopped())
      io_service_.reset();
    error_code ec;
    io_service_.poll_one(ec);
  }
```

Now, when you post functors to `io_service_`, you actually post them to the main GUI thread.

(Certainly, if you use some GUI framework, you should use the appropriate framework method instead of `PeekMessage`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do want to know if there is a way to handle the event using callbacks or functors rather than injecting into the message loop?

Comment: @xftzg I'm not sure what you mean. If you want callbacks/functors to be invoked in the main thread, someone must invoke them, right? In Asio, this is `io_service` who processes the queue of functors, so your main thread must "pump" the `io_service`.

Comment: indeed. that's what i'm getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread is it a webkit similar kind of UI or plain windows forms, because if you are using webkit then u can handle it in a different way.
OR
Try using Delegates.
OR
finally if nothing works out, you can run a while loop checking an vector for any new input and add to the vector from the thread callback function.

I prefer if you could use delegate. (pointer function)

Here is a sample code for pointer function:

define a function like this:

```
typedef boost::function<void(std::string)> fnLog;
```

or if u want to go specifically for windows then

```
typedef void (__stdcall *fnLog)(char* val);
```

fnLog is the function with std::string parameter. then bind your function which is in UI thread to the pointer function

```
fnLog myPointerFunc = boost::bind( &UI::f1, _1);
```

then pass

> myPointerFunc

as callback.

for more reference check on 
http://www.radmangames.com/programming/how-to-use-boost-function

Comment: Yes, I do. (I remembered to reply this before...)

Comment: @xftzg i edited my question with some sample code. Check it out.

Comment: is there any complete samples? I do, as your instruction, bind a callback object in the UI thread, and pass it as a parameter to the thread, like `boost::thread(boost::ref(*this), myPointerFunc);`, and call the callback, `myPointerFunc();`, in the worker thread. However, `myPointerFunc` seems working in the worker thread.