# boost::thread UI interaction

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

How can a spawned boost thread

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&PMyClass::MyThreadfunc,this,callback,boolvar));
```

get UI interaction? I tried passing in boolvar, but it's unresponsive.

Comment: If `boost::thread` acts like `std::thread`, there is no need for `bind` here.

Comment: For std::thread I found http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-3.html. I tried passing a reference, but it didn't work with boost - is that actually possible?

Comment: You could use Boost.Asio's `io_service` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311512/howto-post-messages-between-threads-with-boostasio)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the UI needs to run entirely on your main thread.  (You don't specify which UI library or platform you are using, but this is the case for virtually all major GUIs).  So threads that you create (whether using Boost or otherwise) cannot directly interact with the GUI.

Instead, you must use some form of communication to signal between your worker thread and the main GUI thread for interaction.  Whether it is to signal a redraw of the screen, update a progress bar, change a text field or enable a button - all GUI interaction must happen on the main thread.

A simple way to start would be for your GUI to spawn the worker thread, and periodically poll it on a timer for status updates (by calling appropriate `get` methods on the object maintaining the thread state).  The worker thread then just needs to atomically update its state (ie. using a mutex) so it can be queried, and then it doesn't need to know about the GUI.

The `boolvar` that you pass in will simply be received as a parameter to `MyThreadFunc`.  Inside this worker thread, you will need to provide a processing loop or wait for some signal, otherwise it will run to completion like any other function and return immediately.  If you put a `printf` or logging call at the start and end of your thread function, you should better see what is happening.

This topic is obviously quite complex! We would need more details to provide any more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks. Getting information out of the thread is conveniently done with the callback. But why is there no easy way to get it into it?

Comment: Typically you initialise the thread with all the information it needs to get its job done. This can either be done in the constructor of the object running on the thread (before spawning it) or passing data to the thread function when you actually spawn it.  Is that not easy? If you need to pass data in during the lifetime of the thread, you can use a queue or similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use boost:ref or std::ref like so:

boost::thread t(boost::bind(&PMyClass::MyThreadfunc,this,callback,boost::ref(boolvar)));

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume you are using Windows, though other UIs are similar.

You should use a callback function to update some structure composed in your main View class but make sure it is protected by a mutex when you do. Then use PostMessage() to tell the mainframe that the status of this variable has changed, write a handler for this message in the main UI thread to then read the value and update the control accordingly.