# Boost.Asio Win32 Windows application

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I've created a new Win32 Windows application by using the wizard of Visual Studio. And added Boost.Asio to the project. I wanted to use its deadline_timer to do some repeating work every second. While the timer (and its thread) is working great, I've encouraged the problem that the UI is not updating because io_service.run() blocks the UI thread. After a quick search, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311512/howto-post-messages-between-threads-with-boostasio). It's actually the same problem! So, I moved my code within the GetMessage() loop and changed io_service.run() to io_service.poll_one().

```
// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    //Windows main loop stuff
    if (io.stopped())
        io.reset();
    io.poll_one();
}
```

Well, it's working, but only when there are Windows messages waiting, which is kind of obvious. Is there another thing I can do? Or shall I use a WinAPI thread instead of boost?

Comment: Maybe try `PeekMessage`?

Comment: Also you may want to try `io_service.poll()` instead of `io_service.poll_one()`

Comment: @kenba `io_service.poll()` and `io_service.poll_one()` are equivalent in my project as there is only one handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not portable like Boost, but Windows already provides nice event APIs that integrate with the message loop.

You can use `CreateWaitableTimer` and replace `GetMessage` with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`.  Then the loop will wake for either incoming messages, or timer.  Other types of handles can be used too.

And of course, there's always `SetTimer` which will cause you to receive a `WM_TIMER` message.  But I like waitable timers better.

Comment: `CreateWaitableTimer` is actually a good alternative here as the project does not have to be portable anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Hiale: Yes, if your code already has `GetMessage` in it, then this is tightly coupled to Win32 API, and you shouldn't be afraid to use other Windows functions.  I love `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` and the `Ex` version.  They let me manage just about any set of tasks on a single thread, without needing to worry about race conditions.